# Converting letters using a dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, comparison

I'm trying to write a program that converts letters matching a key in a dictionary to the value associated with that key e.g. if the dictionary is {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'} and the string is 'AAG' the output should be 'TTC'.

EDIT: This is what I've got now thanks to some of your answers:

```
def matching_codons(complements, poolA):
  answer = []
  codon = ''
  counter = 0

  for i in poolA:
    for a in i:
      codon+= complements[a]
      counter += 1
      if counter == 3:
        answer.append(codon)
```

Unfortunately this only translates the first 3 letters - how can I make it keep running through the loop?

Note: poolA is a list of strings e.g. ['AAG', 'TAC', 'CGG', 'GAT', 'TTG', 'GTG', 'CAT', 'GGC', 'ATT', 'TCT']

Note2: I can't hard-code anything like a translation table because technically the dictionary input can be changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another solution is using [maketrans from string](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html)

```
from string import maketrans
complementTrans = maketrans("ACTG", "TGAC")

poolA =  ['AAG', 'TAC', 'CGG', 'GAT', 'TTG', 'GTG', 'CAT', 'GGC', 'ATT', 'TCT']
[codon.translate(complementTrans) for codon in poolA]
```

you get:

```
['TTC', 'ATG', 'GCC', 'CTA', 'AAC', 'CAC', 'GTA', 'CCG', 'TAA', 'AGA']
```

**Bonus**

It is always better to use [biopython library](http://biopython.org/), for example

```
poolA =  ['AAG', 'TAC', 'CGG', 'GAT', 'TTG', 'GTG', 'CAT', 'GGC', 'ATT', 'TCT']

from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC

[str(Seq(seq, IUPAC.unambiguous_dna).complement()) for seq in poolA]
```

you get the same result

**Bonus 2**

Fixing your code, I remove unnecessary variable `counter`

```
poolA =  ['AAG', 'TAC', 'CGG', 'GAT', 'TTG', 'GTG', 'CAT', 'GGC', 'ATT', 'TCT']
complements = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'} 

def matching_codons(complements, poolA):
    answer = []
    for i in poolA:
        codon = ''     # inside of for, codon reset in each iteration
        for a in i:
            codon+= complements[a]
        answer.append(codon)  # outside of secondary for, codon have three leters to end iterations
    return answer

matching_codons(complements, poolA)
```

Comment: I forgot about maketrans! Good call!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't hardcode anything like a translation table because the dictionary is an input - which can then technically be different from what I'm testing with

Comment: @Saltharion review bonus 2 ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Define your dictionary:

```
>>> d = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'}
```

Now, using that dictionary, `AAG` can be translated as follows:

```
>>> ''.join(d[c] for c in 'AAG')
'TTC'
```

Answer (score 1):

So, to take your example here:

```
d = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'}

x = "AAG"
```

To get your result to output "TTC", you can do this:

```
s = ""
for i in x:
    s += d.get(i)
```

A one liner for this:

```
y = "".join([d.get(i) for i in x])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:
complements is the dictionary {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'}

You've got a pretty good gameplan so far, you're only missing a few ideas:
1) complements.values() will give you a view of all the values in the dict (see [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict)).  You want to instead look up the particular value for the character you are on.  As you have already checked if the key is in the dictionary with "if a in complements:", you can look it up with "compliments[a]".
2) Once you've built a complemented codon, you can add it to your list of answers and clear the codon you are building at the moment.

You should note that there are cleaner answers posted here, but I wanted to keep as much of your code as possible.  Please read through the other answers here and try to understand the better methods of achieving your goal as well.

If you have any more questions, please feel free to ask!

Comment: How would I clear the completed codon? The other suggestions worked to convert the letters but now I need to move them to a list, as you said. Would using a counter work?

Comment: I'm assuming that when you build the codon, you will be left with (for example, AAG -> TTC) TTC in codon.  You could add the built codon to the list of answers with "answers.append(codon)".  Then, at the start of your loop you would need to make sure you reset codon to '' (the empty string) or when appending more characters they will all build onto each other.  However, if you build the translated codon without appending with += (for example, with the join commands the others suggested), you would not need to clear as they build from scratch every time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making a translation table:

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> transtab = maketrans("ACTG", "TGAC")
>>> [s.translate(transtab) for s in ['AAG', 'TAC', 'CGG', 'GAT', 'TTG', 'GTG', 'CAT', 'GGC', 'ATT', 'TCT']]
['TTC', 'ATG', 'GCC', 'CTA', 'AAC', 'CAC', 'GTA', 'CCG', 'TAA', 'AGA']
```

Answer (score 0):

use function:

```
def StringChange(str):
    dic = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'G':'C'}
    output = []

    for i in str:
        output += dic[i]

    print("".join(output))
```

It's done. You can use StringChange("AAG"), then get the result "TTC"